# Javascript send value from one file to another file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception

Sorry for my English. I am wondering whether it is possible to send one file to another file variable?

for example

**oneFile.js**

```
var a = true;
```

**twoFile.js**

```
if(a == true) {
alert("hellow");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: include both the .js files in script tags mentioning source path inside html file so as to load the files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if `oneFile.js` is loaded before `twoFile.js`, it will work. Though this exact scenario would be definitely bad practice.

By the way, jQuery works the exact same way, it defines `$` in `jquery.js`, and then you can use it in your own script files.

Answer (score 0):

meskobalazs explained very well, If these two files are in different page I think you can use HTML5 session/local storage

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp